# Загрузка System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation

Tags: c#

После ошибки "Пакет Shared Web Component не был правильно загружен." удалил Visual Studio Community 17 и установил Visual Studio Community 19. Запустил сохраненный проект. Во время выполнения проекта в подключенной библиотеке Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime возникает следующая ошибка:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Сообщение = Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
  Источник = Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime
  Трассировка стека:
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.SessionOptions.CheckLibcVersionGreaterThanMinimum() in C:\agent_work\43\s\csharp\src\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime\SessionOptions.cs:line 170
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.SessionOptions.MakeSessionOptionWithCpuProvider() in C:\agent_work\43\s\csharp\src\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime\SessionOptions.cs:line 89
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

Внутреннее исключение 1:
FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Раньше была проблема "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime", решилась изменением конфигурации с AnyCPU на x64.
Пробовал удалить и установить заново System.Runtime.InteropServices и System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation через NuGet.

Update.

После изменения целевой платформы среды с 4.6.1 на 4.7.2 и переустановки пакетов NuGet, которые были установлены с помощью старой целевой платформы из предупреждения VS, кроме System.Security.Cryptography.Alorithmms ошибка не поменялась. После удаления из NuGet System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation добавил .dll в bin и получил следующую ошибку:
"System.BadImageFormatException
  HResult=0x80131058
  Сообщение = Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Построения ссылок не следует загружать для выполнения.  Их загрузка возможна только в контексте загрузчика только для отображения. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131058)
  Источник = Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime
  Трассировка стека:
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.SessionOptions.CheckLibcVersionGreaterThanMinimum() in C:\agent_work\43\s\csharp\src\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime\SessionOptions.cs:line 170
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.SessionOptions.MakeSessionOptionWithCpuProvider() in C:\agent_work\43\s\csharp\src\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime\SessionOptions.cs:line 89
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

Внутреннее исключение 1:
BadImageFormatException: Не удается загрузить ссылочную сборку для выполнения."

Comment: А в файле конфигурации есть эта сборка? Проверьте блоки <dependentAssembly>.

Comment: В файле app.config есть следующий  блок: "<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>"

Comment: Под какую версию Net Framework собираете?

Comment: @ГеннадийП, в настройках приложения стоит версия 4.6.1

Comment: @AlexanderTelepov [Судя по документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation) если собирать под Net Framework, то минимум под 4.7.1 версию.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, поменял целевую рабочую среду на 4.7.2 во всех проектах решения. Также удалил и установил заново пакеты NuGet, которые были установлены с помощью старой целевой платформы из предупреждения, кроме System.Security.Cryptography.Alorithmms - его удалить не получилось. Ошибка не изменилась.

Comment: @AlexanderTelepov, попробуйте не через nuget, а просто dll подсунуть в bin и уже на нее ссылку прикрепить. Была похожая проблема с библиотекой sharepoint'a. Предварительно удалите пакет NuGet.

Comment: @avocado03, только для System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation это проделать?

Comment: @AlexanderTelepov, да.

Comment: @avocado03, попробовал прикрепить ссылку на dll в bin, получил новую ошибку, она в исправленном вопросе.

Comment: @AlexanderTelepov, тут похожая проблема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1050073/Загрузка-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation?noredirect=1#comment1794028_1050073